# WinRT - Javascript - Is it possible to implement FTP, SSH, SFTP, ...?

Tags: javascript, sockets, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

Is it possible to implement any Network protocol in Metro apps?

Hope WebSockets and XHR aren't the only network tools available.

Hope someone can help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried it myself, but here is the official Microsoft documentation for what you are trying to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452996.aspx

Comment: i can't believe they use innerHTML instead of appendChild and createTextNode !

Comment: @canolucas In their TypeScript playground/demos they also use 'innerText' - Which doesn't work too great in Chrome/Firefox either

Comment: @canolucas if the text is secure, is there any issue associated using innerHTML? performance?

Comment: @Kiewic it is not standard, nor cross brwoser.
This is just another example of microsoft trying to differentiate from the rest and dominate market share in a pedantic way.
and it's ugly

Comment: @canolucas Well, you are right, innerHTML is not mentioned in the W3C DOM specification, but it is supported by the 5 major browsers, and reading statistics, it can be faster than W3C DOM.

Comment: @Kiewic, the fact that it is supported by browser x, browser y and browser z, doesn't make it better in my opinion. it is not standard, and it is the ugly way of doing things, everyone here will tell you the same. the fact that it is a little bit faster deppends of the circumstance and it is due to it's uglyness of just chuncking a piece of text into the DOM tree and see what happens. this is an exagerated example of your argument: "cats live in africa and are felidae, so they must be strong like lions.", you are not being objective pal.

Comment: Actually, innerHTML is part of ES5 (next version of JavaScript), and the IE10 environment implements that part of the spec. So it's effectively standard now, and will be a de jure standard in the future.